# PHP - Manipulating HTML - Adding HREF to images without HREF

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to achieve to following:

In PHP code I have two variables:

One that represets an HTML string

and the other is simply a URL (for example http://example.net/script.php/?param1=x&param2=y)

I want to find all images within the HTML string that does not have HREF to them and add an HREF tag with the URL that the second variable holds.

Example 1:

```
<td valign="middle"><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="http://example.net/email_images/social-facebook.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></td>
```

Result: should stay the same (HREF already exists)

Example 2:

```
<td valign="middle"><img src="http://example.net/email_images/social-facebook.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></td>
```

Result: An HREF tag should be added (HREF did not exist originally)

I am trying to use preg_replace() but struggeling with finding the right regexp.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Thank you! I've used [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) DOM parser and was a able to do it with just a few lines of code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <?php
        $html ='<span><img src="http://imageexists.png" /><span><IMg class>';

        $url = 'www.example.com';

        if(preg_match_all( '/(<img[^>]+>)+/i', $html, $matches)){
            echo '<pre>';

            if(isset($matches[1])){
                foreach($matches[1] as $match){
                    if( strpos($match, 'src=') === false){
                        $notfound = $match;
                        $br = explode('>', $notfound);
                        $final_result = $br[0].' src="'.$url.'" '.'>';
                        $html = str_ireplace( $notfound,$final_result, $html);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo htmlentities($html);
        ?>
```